# How $ψ(x,y)$ can be equal to $C$ when $ψ'$ equals $0$

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

I watched a lesson about exact equations in Khan Academy.
[Link to lesson](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations/exact-equations/v/exact-equations-example-1)

In the video, there is a function called $ψ(x,y)$.

At the end, he found that :
$$
\frac{d}{dx} ψ(x,y) = 0
$$
Then Sal khan said that we can integrate both sides of this equation and reach this:
$$
ψ(x,y)=C
$$
but I can't understand how we can deduce that. We only know that it's derivative with respect to $x$ is zero. How we can say that the function equals to a constant value? Can't we have it as a function of y ?:
$$
ψ(x,y)=f(y)
$$

Comment: Watching the video, he does **not** claim that $\psi$ **must** be constant.  He only notes that *if* $\psi$ were constant that it would still solve the differential equation.

Comment: @Randall I watched it again, you are right. but I think it would be better to write the solution as ψ(,)=() if it could be a function of y, but he didn't . So I guess that he didn't mean that it can be a function of y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a constant, because what your equation requires (in terms of $\Psi$) is that the derivative
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\Psi(x,y(x))=0
$$
and this implies that, along the solutions $y=y(x)$:
$$
\Psi(x,y(x))=C
$$
which you normally leave in implicit form
$$
\Psi(x,y)=C
$$

Comment: How we say y is a function of x? The notation Ψ defines it ?

Comment: $\Phi(x,y)=C$ defines an implicit functional relation between $x$ and $y$ if the conditions in the implicit function theorem are fulfilled.